# Using Notebook Hardware Control (NHC), as soon as it starts, the display dims. How to prevent this?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I am trying to run [Notebook Hardware Control](http://www.pbus-167.com/) to control the fan speed on an HP G60 laptop, running Windows Vista Home Basic SP2.  I don't know if NHC will solve that problem, but when I run NHC, as soon as the nhc.exe program starts up, the display dims to the point that I cannot see it.

What's the problem?  How can I fix it?

I can manually re-adjust the display brightness, but it seems like this should be easy to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom profile to have increased brightness + your custom fan controls